# Pandas Assign Same Number of Random Values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of tasks that I need to randomly assign to workers. Each task should receive one random worker, and each worker should have the same number of tasks as the other workers.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
tasks = ['Task 1','Task 2','Task 3','Task 4','Task 5','Task 6','Task 7','Task 8','Task 9']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tasks':tasks})

    Tasks
0  Task 1
1  Task 2
2  Task 3
3  Task 4
4  Task 5
5  Task 6
6  Task 7
7  Task 8
8  Task 9
```

What I want is to assign a random number between 1-3 to each task. But each number should happen 3 times. So expected result:

```
    Tasks  Assign
0  Task 1       1
1  Task 2       2
2  Task 3       2
3  Task 4       3
4  Task 5       3
5  Task 6       1
6  Task 7       2
7  Task 8       3
8  Task 9       1
```

I've thought about using numpy, but can't find the function that fits my requirement. something like `np.random.randint(1,4, size=(1,9))` perhaps? If there is not an equal number of tasks to workers - assign the last task randomly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `shuffle`

```
a=np.array([1,2,3]*3)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a
Out[230]: array([1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2])
df['New']=a
df
Out[232]: 
    Tasks  New
0  Task 1    1
1  Task 2    3
2  Task 3    3
3  Task 4    2
4  Task 5    1
5  Task 6    2
6  Task 7    3
7  Task 8    1
8  Task 9    2
```

Comment: @MattR yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df['assign'] = np.random.choice([1, 2, 3]*3, size=9, replace=False)
```

Comment: close. but this was an answer set that I received: `array([1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3])`. so this example does have an exact answer, but the random array got it wrong

Comment: Sorry, it should have been `replace=False`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a list that contains each worker ID the required number of times: [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].  Now `shuffle` the list (resulting in a random order).  Assign them in order to the tasks.

Is that enough to lead you to a solution?

---

**Response per OP comment**

Let's let `t` be the quantity of tasks, and `w` be the quantity of workers.  You're worried about the case in which `t / w` is not an integer.  This is a very valid worry.  Let's consider `t=10, w=3`.  The first though t is to simply round up and make a list of 12 worker IDs, shuffle, and assign the first 10.  However, this could give us a list such as

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

When we assign the first 10 IDs, worker 1 has only 2 tasks.  We want the load to be balanced, such that no two workers differ by more than one task.

To fix this, we'll need two lists:

```
body = np.array([1,2,3]*3)
tail = np.array([1,2,3])
np.random.shuffle(tail)
```

From here ...

- append `tail` to `body`; truncate to the quantity of tasks.  This gives you a list of  `t // w` IDs for each worker, with exactly *one* more ID for a subset of the workers.
- shuffle this `body`.
- Make this the new column.

Comment: brilliant solution. just need to get the numpy array logic to work for uneven cases

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

`workers = 9`
`df['a'] = np.random.permutation(np.repeat([1,2,3], math.ceil(workers/3)))`